# Using json file to find shortest path

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a json file with a list of locations and miles. Also have created a function for dijkstra algorithm that takes in 3 parameters. I have loaded my json file  but what three parameters do I use for start end and graph parameters in my function to show the shortest path?

Json file of place and distance

```
{
    "Western Governors University 4001 South 700 East, Salt Lake City, UT 84107": {
        "International Peace Gardens 1060 Dalton Ave S": 7.2,
        "Sugar House Park 1330 2100 S": 3.8,
        "Taylorsville-Bennion Heritage City Gov Off 1488 4800 S": 11.0,
        "Salt Lake City Division of Health Services 177 W Price Ave": 2.2,
        "South Salt Lake Public Works 195 W Oakland Ave": 3.5,
        "Salt Lake City Streets and Sanitation 2010 W 500 S": 10.9,
        "Deker Lake 2300 Parkway Blvd": 8.6,
        "Salt Lake City Ottinger Hall 233 Canyon Rd": 7.6,
        "Columbus Library 2530 S 500 E": 2.8,
        "Taylorsville City Hall 2600 Taylorsville Blvd": 6.4,
        "South Salt Lake Police 2835 Main St": 3.2,
        "Council Hall 300 State St": 7.6,
        "Redwood Park 3060 Lester St": 5.2,
        "Salt Lake County Mental Health 3148 S 1100 W": 4.4,
        "Salt Lake County/United Police Dept 3365 S 900 W": 3.66112816434,
        "West Valley Prosecutor 3575 W Valley Central Sta bus Loop": 7.6,
        "Housing Auth. of Salt Lake County 3595 Main St": 2.0,
        "Utah DMV Administrative Office 380 W 2880 S": 3.6,
        "Third District Juvenile Court 410 S State St": 6.5,
        "Cottonwood Regional Softball Complex 4300 S 1300 E": 1.9,
        "Holiday City Office 4580 S 2300 E": 3.4,
        "Murray City Museum 5025 State St": 2.4,
        "Valley Regional Softball Complex 5100 South 2700 West": 6.4,
        "City Center of Rock Springs 5383 South 900 East #104": 2.4,
        "Rice Terrace Pavilion Park 600 E 900 South": 5.0,
        "Wheeler Historic Farm 6351 South 900 East": 3.6
    },
    "International Peace Gardens 1060 Dalton Ave S": {
        "Western Governors University 4001 South 700 East, Salt Lake City, UT 84107": 7.2,
        "Sugar House Park 1330 2100 S": 7.1,
        "Taylorsville-Bennion Heritage City Gov Off 1488 4800 S": 6.4,
        "Salt Lake City Division of Health Services 177 W Price Ave": 6.0,
        "South Salt Lake Public Works 195 W Oakland Ave": 4.8,
        "Salt Lake City Streets and Sanitation 2010 W 500 S": 1.6,
        "Deker Lake 2300 Parkway Blvd": 2.8,
        "Salt Lake City Ottinger Hall 233 Canyon Rd": 4.8,
        "Columbus Library 2530 S 500 E": 6.3,
        "Taylorsville City Hall 2600 Taylorsville Blvd": 7.3,
        "South Salt Lake Police 2835 Main St": 5.3,
        "Council Hall 300 State St": 4.8,
        "Redwood Park 3060 Lester St": 3.0,
        "Salt Lake County Mental Health 3148 S 1100 W": 4.6,
        "Salt Lake County/United Police Dept 3365 S 900 W": 4.5,
        "West Valley Prosecutor 3575 W Valley Central Sta bus Loop": 7.4,
        "Housing Auth. of Salt Lake County 3595 Main St": 6.0,
        "Utah DMV Administrative Office 380 W 2880 S": 5.0,
        "Third District Juvenile Court 410 S State St": 4.8,
        "Cottonwood Regional Softball Complex 4300 S 1300 E": 9.5,
        "Holiday City Office 4580 S 2300 E": 10.9,
        "Murray City Museum 5025 State St": 8.3,
        "Valley Regional Softball Complex 5100 South 2700 West": 6.9,
        "City Center of Rock Springs 5383 South 900 East #104": 10.0,
        "Rice Terrace Pavilion Park 600 E 900 South": 4.4,
        "Wheeler Historic Farm 6351 South 900 East": 13.0
    },
    "Sugar House Park 1330 2100 S": {
        "Western Governors University 4001 South 700 East, Salt Lake City, UT 84107": 3.8,
        "International Peace Gardens 1060 Dalton Ave S": 7.1,
        "Taylorsville-Bennion Heritage City Gov Off 1488 4800 S": 9.2,
        "Salt Lake City Division of Health Services 177 W Price Ave": 4.4,
        "South Salt Lake Public Works 195 W Oakland Ave": 2.8,
        "Salt Lake City Streets and Sanitation 2010 W 500 S": 8.6,
        "Deker Lake 2300 Parkway Blvd": 6.3,
        "Salt Lake City Ottinger Hall 233 Canyon Rd": 5.3,
        "Columbus Library 2530 S 500 E": 1.6,
        "Taylorsville City Hall 2600 Taylorsville Blvd": 10.4,
        "South Salt Lake Police 2835 Main St": 3.0,
        "Council Hall 300 State St": 5.3,
        "Redwood Park 3060 Lester St": 6.5,
        "Salt Lake County Mental Health 3148 S 1100 W": 5.6,
        "Salt Lake County/United Police Dept 3365 S 900 W": 5.8,
        "West Valley Prosecutor 3575 W Valley Central Sta bus Loop": 5.7,
        "Housing Auth. of Salt Lake County 3595 Main St": 4.1,
        "Utah DMV Administrative Office 380 W 2880 S": 3.6,
        "Third District Juvenile Court 410 S State St": 4.3,
        "Cottonwood Regional Softball Complex 4300 S 1300 E": 3.3,
        "Holiday City Office 4580 S 2300 E": 5.0,
        "Murray City Museum 5025 State St": 6.1,
        "Valley Regional Softball Complex 5100 South 2700 West": 9.7,
        "City Center of Rock Springs 5383 South 900 East #104": 6.1,
        "Rice Terrace Pavilion Park 600 E 900 South": 2.8,
        "Wheeler Historic Farm 6351 South 900 East": 7.4
    }
```

Algorithm function for shortest path

```
def dijkstrasShortestDistance(start, end, graph):
    visited = chainingHashMap()

    paths = list()
    paths.append(([start], 0))
    while len(paths) > 0:
        nowPath = paths.pop()
        finalItem = nowPath[0][-1]
        hasVisited = visited.get(finalItem)[0]
        if not hasVisited:
            visited.insert(finalItem, True)
        else:
            continue
        if finalItem == end:
            return nowPath
        nextTuple = graph.get(finalItem)
        if not nextTuple[0]:
            continue
        nextNodes = nextTuple[1]
        for nextNodes in nextNodes:
            newPath = list(nowPath[0])
            newPath.append(nextNodes[0])
            newDistance = nowPath[1]
            newDistance += nextNodes[1]
            paths.append((newPath, newDistance))
        paths = sorted(paths, key=lambda tuple_item: tuple_item[0])
    return (list(), 0)
```

Main section to fun program

```
distance = load_json(os.path.join(mainDirectory, 'distanceTable.json'))
print(dijkstrasShortestDistance(not sure how to get info from json into here)
```

Answer (score 0):

Each location is a graph node.  Each destination indicates an edge; the following distance is an edge value.  For starters, you have:

```
"Western Governors University 4001 South 700 East, Salt Lake City, UT 84107": {
    "International Peace Gardens 1060 Dalton Ave S": 7.2,
    "Sugar House Park 1330 2100 S": 3.8,
    ...
```

This involves three nodes, one for each location; let's call them WGU, IPG, SHP.  You also have two edges with values (weight or cost):

```
src  dst   cost
WGU  IPG   7.2
WGU  SHP   3.8
```

You have to iterate through your input to build the graph.  Since you have all of the input conveniently in a dict, I expect that you can continue from here.

Comment: So you mean something like this.                                                   
 for v in distance.value(): print(dijkstrasShortestDistance(v[dista], v[dst], v,[cost]))

Comment: No; this has several problems.  There are several undefined symbols, your function arguments do not appear to match your parameters, and you need to either build a graph, or reference your nested dict to get the information.

Comment: "What do I do after this" is out of scope for Stack Overflow.  Please see [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: ok I created a dot file with a digraph that printed it out like this "Western Governors University 4001 South 700 East, Salt Lake City, UT 84107" -> "International Peace Gardens 1060 Dalton Ave S"[label="7.2",weight="7.2"]; is this something like you were saying? If so are the key the label and the weight?